# Is it safe to delete inodes?

Tags: magento-1.9, inode, mod-pagespeed

I am using google mod_pagespeed in Magento 1.9 and I have found what appears to be a very large collection of cache data from mod_pagespeed for this site found under:

```
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/v3/
```

`/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/v3/` - has some 14million inodes and due to that I am getting this Error message

> E_WARNING: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please
>   verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (/var/lib/php/session).

Is it safe to delete these inodes?